# Changing password of a remote Linux system using Python (sftp)

Tags: python, linux, sftp, paramiko, change-password

It seems very simple, but I searched multiple resources but could not find an answer on how to change a remote Linux system password using Python and with SFTP.

```
def changepwd():
    sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
    #change password of root on remote server
```

Are there any built-in modules that I can use to change the password?
Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for all you help. This is how I changed the passwd for 'root'.

```
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, username=Name, password=Pwd)
print "Connection succesfully established ...with %s " % hostname

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo -e "newpasswd\newPasswd" | passwd')
print "stderr: ", stderr.readlines()
print "pwd: ", stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: You cannot change password with SFTP protocol – It does not matter what Python library/module you use, or if you use any other language or tool – SFTP *protocol* does no have a capability to change passwords. – You can change a password with SSH protocol or shell though.

Comment: Seconding what @MartinPrikryl said: can't be done using that protocol; at least not in a way deemed safe. **if** you were sftp'ing as root you could just replace the shadow file, but that would border on criminally insane.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, tink thank you for your comments. If I were to do it via SSH are there any built-in modules that I can use?

Comment: So looks like I  need to do something like this `import paramiko
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('<hostname>', username='<username>', 
   key_filename='private-key-file>')`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change password with SFTP protocol.

You can change password with SSH protocol. But the SSH protocol API for changing a password is not support by the most widespread SSH server – OpenSSH. Nor it is supported by the most widespread Python SSH library – Paramiko. So this most likely won't work for you anyway.

So in the end the only viable option is to execute a relevant shell command (`passwd` or `chpasswd`) via SSH (e.g. using Paramiko).